# fix pandas on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python3

I did probably something wrong.
When a run my python3 script which contains only `import pandas`, I get the error

```
RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you just google the warning (not error), you get some helpful pages like [this issue on Anaconda's GitHub](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6678), and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40845304/4518341)

Comment: A warning is not an error.  Please include the script if you get an error from a script so people can try on their system.

Comment: The procedure of uninstall and install worked for me as in the above mentioned link.

Comment: You where right. I had to show my script. But because I just started, the script had just a few lines of code. The warming/error was created on the line with “import pandas”, that’s why I did not include the script.

Comment: it seems the question is solved, you should close it